# Why do we need EIGRP AS numbers when we have EIGRP RID?

Tags: cisco, routing, router, protocol-theory, eigrp

I understand that the EIGRP routers need to have the same AS number to peer with each other. But why can't we just use EIGRP Router ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want separate EIGRP ASes on one router, then that would not be possible with only the Router ID, and you can use the same Router ID on multiple ASes. Those are two completely separate functions. The Router ID is unique per AS.

For example, you could have a router with multiple ASes:

```
router eigrp 10
 no auto-summary
 network 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0
!
router eigrp 20
 no auto-summary
 network 20.20.20.0 255.255.255.0
!
```

The Router ID could be the same or different for each AS. Having the same Router ID simplifies documentation and troubleshooting because it can be based on a loopback address.

Each AS can use different interfaces and can advertise different sets of prefixes. You could even have some overlapping interfaces/prefixes, but that has nothing to do with the Router ID.

Comment: This is correct but it's worth noting that multiple IGP instances (especially EIGRP) don't always behave as one might expect in terms of separation/convergence.

Answer (score 0):

As EIGRP is interior gateway protocol . EIGRP algorithm is designed in such a way that EIGRP with same atonomous number .

EIGRP router will speak to another router which is in same atonomous system number .